# CKEditor: Custom styling UL/LI elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do I customise the way CKEditor writes specific tags?

I'm using CKEditor in a little tool to help our editorial teams generate ready-to-send HTML emails using a responsive template. As such, I'm applying inline styles to elements (rather than using CSS classes).

I'm struggling a little with implementing styling for unordered lists. I need to apply a style attribute to both the UL and LI elements but I can't seem to find a way to do so via the Styles list.

I haven't found any solution to my first thought, "have a single style affect multiple elements in different ways" so I'm now wondering if I can configure CKEditor so that whenever it writes a UL element, it includes the necessary style block, and ditto for LI elements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dataProcessor` to force the way the elements are build:

```
dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
        ul: function( el ) {
            if ( !el.attributes.style) {
                el.attributes['style'] = 'list-style: square';
            }
        },
        li: function( el ) {
            if ( !el.attributes.style) {
                el.attributes['style'] = 'color: red';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This way when the `ul` element will be written - it will have the style `list-style: square` and the `li` element will have `color: red` as it's style.

> It's important to note that the value is available using the `getData()` function of the ckeditor or once you switch from edit to source mode and back to edit mode.

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v6zf2vwm/